# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning async await

Tags: javascript, async-await, apollo-server

Following is my code for onDisconnect function in a graphql (apollo-server) server (but is not graphql specific). It contains a postgres transaction, which is used through the `DB` adapter. The code works but I keep receiving warnings whenever there are errors throw from await. Below is my code as well as the warnings. I am new to async/await, not sure what I have done wrong.

```
onDisconnect: () => {
    try {
        DB.tx(async t => {
                const do_something = await t.any(`SELECT *
                                                  FROM something`, []).catch((e) => { throw `error deleting socket` })
                ... more awaits here ...
                console.log(do_something)
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
},


(node:5640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
(rejection id: 3)
(node:5640) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I also tried the following:

```
onDisconnect: () => {
    try {
        return DB.tx(async t => {
                const do_something = await t.any(`SELECT *
                                                  FROM something`, []).catch((e) => { throw `error deleting socket` })
                ... more awaits here ...
                console.log(do_something)
                return {
                    success: 1
                }
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        throw error
    }
},
```

Export as function for other cases works without warning, for example:

```
export function do_another_thing(...) {
        try {
            return DB.tx(async t => {
                    const do_something = await t.any(`SELECT *
                                                      FROM nothing`, []).catch((e) => { throw `error fetching data` })
                    ... more awaits here ...
                    console.log(do_something)
                    return {
                        success: 1
                    }
                }
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            throw error
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `catch` the `await`s directly:

```
 export function do_another_thing(...) {
   return DB.tx(async t => {
     try {
       const do_something = await t.any(`SELECT * FROM nothing`, []).catch((e) => { throw `error fetching data` })
       //.. more awaits here ...
       console.log(do_something)
       return {
         success: 1
       };          
    } catch(error) {
       console.log(error);
       // handle the error properly!
    }
 });

}
```

*Protip: Rethrowing is not handling...*

Comment: But this export function as I mentioned in the question works without warnings. I am having trouble only with the graphql `onDisconnect` on the top that does not expect anything in return

Comment: @pewpewlasers you do not handle errors in all three cases.

Comment: I am a little confused, a little pointer on how to do that in the first scenario where I don't really need to return anything (success or failure)? Also in my scenario I do not really need to process the error so isn't re-throwing enough in the third scenario?